# Unknown function (set_sources_assignment_filter)

Tags: chromium, gn

I'm attempting to build an older version of Chromium (64.0.3282.123) on Linux.  Running `gn args out/Default` produces the error

```
Generating files...
ERROR at //build/config/BUILDCONFIG.gn:495:1: Unknown function.
set_sources_assignment_filter(sources_assignment_filter)
^----------------------------
```

My build arguments are

```
is_debug = false
is_clang = true
symbol_level = 2
dcheck_always_on = false
is_component_build = false
target_os = "android"
target_cpu = "arm64"
blink_symbol_level = 0
v8_symbol_level = 0
ignore_elf32_limitations = true
```

Comment: Looks like it was using deprecated `set_sources_assignment_filter` as mentioned here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1018739 Also, I think Chromium used GYP instead of GN at this time, not sure though